# Invalid column name 'tp_IsCurrent'

Tags: sharepoint-server

I recently migrated a publishing site from a SharePoint Windows based Web Application to a SharePoint 2013 Claims based Web App.

I also migrated the users of this site from Windows to Claims Authentication using this script:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://demo.com.au
$wa | Get-SPContentDatabase | ft Name
$arguments = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPMigrateUserParameters
$arguments.AddDatabaseToMigrate($wa.ContentDatabases[9]) 
$wa.MigrateUsersToClaims($farmAdmin, $false, $arguments)
```

I performed these steps for other site collections within the same Web Application and none have issues except one site collection.

The issue is that only a site collection administrator can change the "Master Page", "Page layouts and Site templates" links under site settings. Other users less than site collection administrator receive the error: `Exception from HRESULT : 0x80131904`.

In the logs I receive a strange error: `Invalid column name 'tp_IsCurrent'` - from the SQL executed below

This is a field in the AllUserData table. The definition I found for this field is:

> tp_IsCurrent: When a file is checked out, tp_IsCurrent is set to false on that file’s record, and a new line is created for the checked-out version of the file (wherein tp_IsCurrent becomes true).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer for my question and hope this could save some of yours time. 
It was due to unique permission for hidden "Cache Profile" list. I have written a blog on this at below link.
[Click to see more details.](http://meandmysharepoint.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/sharepoint-2013-exception-from-hresult.html)